# I'm making a card game and I want to change the image once it has been clicked

Tags: javascript

```js
import Deck from "./deck2.js"

const deck = new Deck()
var playerCardImg = deck.cards[0].image;

createCard()
createCard()
createCard()


var cards = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("card"))
cards.forEach(card => {
    card.addEventListener("click", () => {
        card.classList.toggle("flipCard")
        
        var playerCard = deck.pop()
        playerCardImg = playerCard.image
        cardImg.setAttribute("src", playerCardImg); 
        innerInnerCardDiv.appendChild(cardImg)
    });
});

function createCard() {
    var cardImg = document.createElement('IMG')
    var cardText = document.createElement('h1')
    var cardDiv = document.createElement('div')
    var innerCardDiv = document.createElement('div')
    var innerInnerCardDiv = document.createElement('div')
    var innerInnerCardDiv2 = document.createElement('div')

    cardDiv.classList.add("maincontainer")
    innerCardDiv.classList.add("card")
    innerInnerCardDiv2.classList.add("back")   

    cardImg.setAttribute("src", playerCardImg); 
    cardImg.classList.add("front")

    cardText.innerText = "Beast Battle"

    document.body.appendChild(cardDiv)
    cardDiv.appendChild(innerCardDiv)
    innerCardDiv.appendChild(innerInnerCardDiv)
    innerCardDiv.appendChild(innerInnerCardDiv2)
    innerInnerCardDiv.appendChild(cardImg)
    innerInnerCardDiv2.appendChild(cardText)

    return cardDiv
}
```

I thought by doing this:

```
cardImg.setAttribute("src", playerCardImg);
```

I'd be able to change the image but it doesn't work
Note: When I click the card, it does flip. The problem is that since it doesn't change the image, all the cards have the same image.

Edit: here's a link to all the files

github.com/LyshaJaufar/CardGame.git

Comment: Please share a stackblitz link to your code or add dependent files here.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Use a brief but descriptive summary of your problem as the title of your question."_

Comment: Can you please describe _how_ your code doesn't work? For example, explain how your code doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure how to reply to comments directly but here's a link to all of the code:
https://github.com/LyshaJaufar/CardGame.git

Comment: I have three cards, each of them has a backface and a frontface.  What I want is for when I click a given card, it flips and an image is loaded. Initially, I'd set the frontface equal to a default value(I deleted that part later), but I want that image value to change once I click the card and it flips to the front such that the front no longer has the default image. The issue is that no image is when I do this, no image is loading.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
element.onclick = functionRef
```

See [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).